# ¿Cómo usar el DbContext dentro de pruebas unitarias en Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, test

¿Cómo puedo hacer para ejecutar operaciones contra DB desde proyecto de prueba unitarias usando el DbContext?

("En el proyecto web, obvio que la conexion a la DB funciona bien")

Estoy tratando de ejecutar métodos contra DB y aunque instancio la clase y todo debería funcionar bien me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

***The underlying provider failed on Open. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No se ha encontrado la ruta de acceso de la red***

He leído sobre MOCK pero en realidad  no deseo utilizarlo a menos que sea estrictamente necesario, prefiero utilizar ahora la conexión a la base de datos de desarrollo.

Código prueba:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetList()
{
    Usuario usuario = GetUser();
    CRMv2_ClienteEntities db = new CRMv2_ClienteEntities();
    ISolicitudRepository solicitudRepository = new SolicitudRepository();
    var lst = solicitudRepository.GetListViewModel(usuario, db);

    Assert.IsNotNull(usuario);
    Assert.IsNotNull(db);
    Assert.IsNotNull(solicitudRepository);
    Assert.IsNotNull(lst);
}
```

Código del contexto de  la Db:

```
namespace EX_CentralCompras.DataModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class CRMv2_ClienteEntities : DbContext
    {
        public CRMv2_ClienteEntities() : base("name=CRMv2_ClienteEntities")
        {
        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<A_Empresa> A_Empresa { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_CC_EstadoSolicitud> A_CC_EstadoSolicitud { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_Contador> A_Contador { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_Contrato> A_Contrato { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_Articulo> A_Articulo { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_CC_SolicitudDetalle> A_CC_SolicitudDetalle { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_InfoLibre> A_InfoLibre { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_InfoLibreValor> A_InfoLibreValor { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_CC_SolicitudDetalle_Proveedor> A_CC_SolicitudDetalle_Proveedor { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_DocumentoCabecera> A_DocumentoCabecera { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_DocumentoLineaPedido> A_DocumentoLineaPedido { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_Proyecto> A_Proyecto { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<A_CC_Solicitud> A_CC_Solicitud { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: En una prueba unitaria debes evitar ir a la base de datos. Para eso ya tendrías que hacer pruebas de integración. 

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un mock del DbContext (con Moq por ejemplo) y pasarle el mock al repository.

Comment: Tal vez pudieras utilizar una [base de datos en memoria](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/) (In-Memory) para las pruebas

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿Por qué le pones virtual a los DbSet?